# Define two global variables HOST and PORT and pass them to the .bind() method

Tags: python, sockets, methods, tcp, pycharm

I'm a beginner and I can't quite get the task right. Here is the task: "*According to the TCP flow diagram, now the .bind() method must be executed. The parameters of the .bind() method depend on the address family. In our case of IPv4 (socket.AF_INET) it is a tuple consisting of two parameters: (host,port). For this, define two global variables HOST and PORT and pass them to the .bind() method. The host is either a string with a hostname like 'www.htw-berlin.de' or an IPv4 address. Choose here the IPv4 address of your local host (localhost). The port is an integer between 1 and 65535 (0 is reserved). It is best to choose a number > 1023 (root privileges may be required below this)."*

I program in PyCharm and this is my code:

```
import socket
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
def f ():
    HOST='127.0.0.1'
    PORT=1337
server_socket.bind(('HOST', PORT))
server_socket.listen(1)

while True:
    (client_socket, addr) = server_socket.accept()
    print(client_socket.recv(1024)) here
```

Can someone please tell me how to do this correctly ?

Comment: Don't put `HOST` in quotes else you are passing the word "HOST".

Comment: Also, there doesn't seem to be any need for the function `f` (you aren't even calling it). Just define the variables in the global namespace, like the assignment tells you to do.

Answer (score 0):

The basic server pattern:

```
import socket

server_socket = socket.socket() # defaults are IPv4 TCP

# ONLY serves locally. Use '' to serve
# on all available interfaces on the host.
HOST = '127.0.0.1' # global
PORT = 1337

server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
server_socket.listen() # default is fine

while True:
    client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
    ...
```